# On Heroku when sending mail through action mailer gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I created rails g mailer from this [reference site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html). It is working fine on local there is no error. I also added {config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp} with did smtp settings and deployed on heroku,

but now its giving error

We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your exact mailer settings ?

Comment: config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => "587",
  :domain               => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name            => 'romanchsharma@gmail.com',
  :password             => '*********',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

Comment: change authentication => login and try

Answer (score 2):

For sending mail in production environment, do following thing -

```
 1. In config/environments/production.rb

   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: 'smtp.mail.com',
     port: 587,
     domain: 'YOUR_DOMAIN_GOES_HERE',
     user_name: 'YOUR_EMAIL_ID_GOES_HERE',
     password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE',
     authentication: 'plain',
     enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

and deploy this change on heroku and if you again found any error there, please check -
         `heroku stack:set cedar-14`

then again deploy on heroku - `git push heroku master`.

Try it.

Comment: Sorry I have the same settings but it's not work for me. I also check heroku stack:set cedar-14

Comment: @RomanchSharma........Can you please check `heroku logs` and check what error is coming.

Comment: WARNING: Toolbelt v3.37.1 update available.
only this warning is coming rest is ok

Comment: the first answre is The Heroku platform itself doesn’t provide an email service. I think this is correct answer.

Comment: No, i am using email service on Heroku plateform and it's working.

Comment: @RomanchSharma Can you post `heroku logs`. So, i found out what is the problem there.

Comment: are you using free email services sir

Comment: No, I am just using simple rails mail setting.

Comment: I am facing same problem 1 time and check heroku logs and found that i need to set heroku stack to cedar-14. That's why i asking you that write `heroku logs` here

Comment: heroku logs are too long cant copy past like this here.

Comment: there is no error on heroku logs. the app is runing fine only unable to send email.

Comment: all codes are exect same as link provided about of active mailer

Comment: But "We're sorry, but something went wrong" render, when there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku platform itself doesn’t provide an email service. You need to use external services. Read their documentation about how to [send emails from your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp).

Comment: i tryed heroku addons:create sendgrid to add  external email services but i get !    `addons:create` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

Comment: is there any other way to check my email settings working correctly.